# after update firebase I got on real device error in android error message > zzdk: keyset not found, will generate a new one

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

it works fine on emulater but in real device I got this error in the log caty

> zzdk: keyset not found, will generate a new one
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: can't read keyset; the pref value
> GenericIdpKeyset does not exist

and I have latest service-json file and I put  the SHA-1 & SHA-256

Comment: same thing had to me. did you found a solution for this?

Comment: Ive done a lot of changes at once so I don't know what was the problem.!  but one important thing was I didn't send proper  *phone number format* to the  server.

Comment: wow you are correct! i forgot to give it usa code ex: `+1 555-555-5555`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears as @ikhlas ahmed confirmed the solution was

> Just Make sure to send a proper phone number format to the server/api

ex: +`1 555-555-5555`